# Capture video screenshot using canvas

Tags: javascript, html, video, canvas, webrtc

I used `getusermedia()` to stream webcam and microphone to browser. But when captured video using canvas it outputs a black image!
`ctx.drawImage(video, 0,0,640,480);
window.open(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'));`
why its showing a black image and how to fix it? 
Ingmars solved mah problem.

Now if i want a max 10sec video i thought of looping through frames and joining the .png one after another. Is it possible?
If not any alternative?

Comment: Did you used some kind of loop to `drawImage`? It will not work if you called it just once. You need to update canvas context on each frame.

Comment: What kinda loop is to be used @Ingmars

Comment: @Ingmars THE setinterval() should start at start of video streaming `video.play()` or
when the `.takesnapshot` button is clicked?

Comment: Video should be playing already for setInterval to work. Canvas is just a mirror of the video element's current content. If video is not playing, canvas will not show anything and subsequently will not be able to `toDataURL()`.

Comment: So the setinterval() should start before clicking `.takesnapshot` ? 
@Ingmars

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55583/discussion-between-ingmars-and-user3508453).

Comment: If all you want is a screenshot, then no loop is needed....

Comment: Then what requires a loop? @bwtrent

Comment: If you want continuous captures for a video feed. Also, Intervals are not good loops for image capture anyways. If you want to use a loop use requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: And if i want a short 10sec video to be recorded? @bwtrent

Comment: Then yes, a loop would be needed. If that is what you want, update your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a loop:

```
//assuming canvas, ctx and video is set previously and available in all scopes.

var fps = 1000/25; //Approximately 25 frames per second

var videoDrawInterval = setInterval( function() {
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
}, fps );


something.onclick = function() {
    clearInterval( videoDrawInterval );

    var snapshotImg = new Image();
    snapshotImg.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.5); //Second param is jpg quality

    var win = window.open( '', 'Snapshot', 'width=640, height=480'  );
    win.document.body.appendChild( snapshotImg );
}
```

Bear in mind that jpeg compression is not supported in all browsers, so for testing I'd suggest using png format:

```
canvas.toDataURL( 'image/png' );
```

Comment: not if she/he only wants a screenshot, there is no need for a loop if it is just a single screenshot.